# Filter sentinel 2 images that have empty areas

Tags: sentinel-2, sentinel-hub

When trying to download a clipped area from the sentinelhub API python library, it returns images from 2 different orbits: One that passes right on top (Right pic), and the image is full, and a orbit next to (Left pic), but its image is cut due to deformations.

[image: Case 2]      [image: Case 1]

Checking the metadata in the sentinelhub website, there is a parameter called `no_data_pixel-percentage`, but that parameter is not included in the metadata returned by the API. Does anyone have found a solution to filter the good ones?

Answer (score 0):

`sentinelhub` Python package allows you to get a no-data (i.e. transparency) mask for each image. Example, how to do this, can be found in [documentation, chapter 10](https://sentinelhub-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/ogc_request.html#Example-10:-Using-Custom-URL-Parameters).

Basically you have to specify `custom_url_params={CustomUrlParam.TRANSPARENT: True}` when you initialize your WMS or WCS request. Downloaded images will have one channel more then before and the last channel will have information about no data.

Once you have this channel you can decide which images to use. The package does not have a "maximal no-data percentage" parameter with which you could download only images that have low no-data percentage. However you can use `time_difference` parameter to merge images from multiple acquisitions into a single one as shown in [documentation examples, chapter 8](https://sentinelhub-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/ogc_request.html#Example-8:-Merging-two-or-more-download-requests-into-one).